# How to work with Payroll Item with IDS V3?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are building an application that gets the payroll items from QuickBooks online  and Quickbooks desktop using account using IPP QuickBooks API – V3. We would like to use the retrieved payroll items to set payroll Item wage for Time Activity.  We checked the supported objects and did not see payroll Item.
[V3 Supported objects](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations)
. Can you please advise on how we can do that?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not on the list of [supported objects](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations), then it's not supported yet, and thus you can't work with that data yet.